# binomial coefficient and recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

any hints on how to solve the recurrence relations for the following binomial coefficient

\begin{equation}
  {n \choose k}=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $k\in\{0,n\}$}.\\
    {n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-1 \choose k}, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $ 0\ge k \le n $

Comment: Sometimes known as the Pascal Identity. Several combinatorial proofs have been given on MSE, also "algebraic" proofs. Wikipedia, now that you know the name,might also help.

Comment: What's the question? This **is** a recurrence relation.

Comment: I don't see the relation to the post you have mentioned @peterwhy

Comment: Sorry, I now noticed you reverted another editor's change, back to $0\ge k \le n$. Do you wish to ask about the case where $k\le 0$?

Comment: Nope that's the part where i need hint @peterwhy